# Is there any way to abstract all unique values of sum after summation?

Tags: summation, algorithms

Suppose we have 'n' numbers take 4 for simplicity like 1,2,6,7 and there sum is 'S=16'.So, Is there any way to find all unique values from 'S' using only 'n'?thank in advance..

Comment: Can't $S$ be anything? I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: "numbers" = integers , positive integres, .. ? In any case the answer is NO: knowing S is just reducing the "degrees of freedom" from $n$ to $n-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of the question:

Given $a_1 + a_2 + \ldots +a_n = S$, can we find the values of $a_i$ $(i=1,\ldots,n)$?

The short answer is **no** if $n \ge 2$. Take $n = 2$ for example:

$$x + y = S.$$

Then there are infinitely many choices $(x,y)=(x,S-x)$ which satisfy this equation. It's basically the equation of a line in the $x$-$y$ plane.